# Loading templates with backbone js

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm starting in javascript development, and did a simple project with node.js as a rest API and a client using backbone, everything look perfectly till I want to get my templates out of my js.

I found different approaches, some of them with some time (like one year old) but I can't understand which one could be better:

- A .js file with a var with the html code

  pros -> easy to load, easy to pass to underscore to compile it.

  cons -> scape every single line.

  ```
  app.templates.view = " \
  <h3>something code</h3> \
  ";
  ```

  load template:

  ```
  template: _.template(app.templates.view)
  ```

[External template in Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366733/external-template-in-underscore)

- Use require.js to load with text plug-in.

  pros -> load different templates as needed.

  cons -> I don't like the approach to put everything inside a "loader" function...

  ```
  define(["TemplateEngine", "text!templates/template.html"], function(...
  ```

[RequireJS: Loading modules including templates and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917639/requirejs-loading-modules-including-templates-and-css)

- A function that loads the templates with an AJAX petition.

  pros -> You can load the template that you need and adds local storage posibilities.

  cons -> Seems that I have to merge all my templates into one file for production environments.

  ```
  function() {

  var templateLoader = {... $.get calls ...}
  ```

[Best way to asynchronously load underscore templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542089/best-way-to-load-asynchronously-undescore-templates)

- And a Jquery plug-in for template loading that I really liked but it seems that it didn't go to release?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

It seems that require is the best approach, but maybe I'm missing something, I do wan't to make things as clean as possible since I'm in the learning/having fun phase :D

Any good article or github project with a good structure or any light on this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Excuse any major spelling mistake, not an English speaker :)

--EDIT--
found some interesting videos to understand how to start and wrap things with require.js
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGlDR1QiV3A

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-wjQjsryMY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using require.js with text plugin. Mixing html templates as strings in javascript variable is bad idea, as well as using something like `<script type="text/template"></script>`.

Here is one very good series on backbone.js which covers template loading and project build as well: http://dailyjs.com/2012/11/29/backbone-tutorial-1/. Github project is also provided there.

Comment: Thx i'll have a look, the <script type="text/template" is a bad approach because the template is inside the js or why?

Comment: You use Backbone which is basically a very good utility for adding structure to code and separating different tasks (data processing / view rendering) between different types of objects. Saving client-side templates as separate files is also a good way for adding structure (just as saving your .js files in /js folder, stylesheets in /css folder etc). Keep your server-side templates (or static html pages) clean and easy to maintain. Just imagine if you need 10 different templates on one page - adding them all to html head inside script tags will lead to a great mess in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Require is a good option from the ones you listed.

Is there a reason you haven't considered simply:

1. Storing templates in the pages that use them as `<script type='text/template'>` nodes?
2. Storing templates as text (non-JS) files and loading them via XHR on pages that use them?