# Marionette.js showing CollectionView

Tags: javascript, html, marionette

I am a beginner in Marionette and trying to get a view output to be like this:

```html
<div class="style_title">Component Library</div>
<ul class="style_content">
    <li class="style_item">title1</li>
    <li class="style_item">title2</li>
</ul>
```

This is ItemView and CollectionView:

```js
var TitleView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
       template: _.template("<%=title%>"),
       tagName: "li",
       className: "style_item"
    });

    var TitleListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: "ul", 
        className: "style_content",
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
            ComponentService.getComponents().forEach(function (title) {
                this.collection.add(title);
            }.bind(this));
        },
        childView: TitleView  
    });
```

How to add div attribute to get a needed output. There is a possibility to use text!js, but I can't get things together. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `add div attribute`

Comment: I mean this div element(<div class="style_title">Component Library</div>) before CollectionView sequence, so that output be

Comment: what `sequence`? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What should I add or remove form CollecionView to get an html output like this 
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<div class="style_title">Component Library</div>
<ul class="style_content">
    <li class="style_item">title1</li>
    <li class="style_item">title2</li>
</ul>

Comment: And you don't want to use `<script type="text/template">`?

Comment: This template is situated not in this file. How could i "tell" js to search for "#some_tag"? For example, my views are in app/views and templates are in app/templates.

Comment: Well to do so you need to link your javascript file in the html template like `<script src="your_js_file"></script>` else you can use `requirejs` and use [requirejs text](https://github.com/requirejs/text)

Comment: might be a useful [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097535/loading-templates-with-backbone-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CompositeView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html) instead of Collection view in which you can pass template not just set a tag and specify container for items.

```
var TitleListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: _.template('<div class="style_title">Component Library</div><ul class="style_content"></ul>'),
    childViewContainer: 'ul.style_content',
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
        ComponentService.getComponents().forEach(function (title) {
            this.collection.add(title);
        }.bind(this));
    },
    childView: TitleView
});
```

Actually in the next versions of Marionette they plan to remove CompositeView and allow to pass template to CollectionView.

Comment: It can't find childViewContainer. Is it value is taken from template?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. That's exacly what I want. It's by default adding collectionView in div. Is it ok? 

<div>
   What_I_Want
</div>

Comment: As stated in docs in childViewContainer option you can specify a jQuery selector to put the `childView` instances into. So yes, you can put your items into any element inside your template you want.